# Filtering out answered questions on main feed

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

I'd like to be able to view the main feed (which filters out uninteresting questions) while also filtering out already answered (with accepted answers) questions. I happen to get into questions a lot of time and then figure out I missed the fact they were already answered because I just didn't notice.

Comment: You might find the Custom Filters useful, cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147134/295232