# How to find questions with 'no answers' and 'my tags'?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search, my-tags, no-answers

There should be a nice filter of a tab or an other pretty way to combine the path:

```
unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers
```

with

```
unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags
```

like

```
unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags;noanswers
```

I want to see questions with zero answers that has any of my favorite tags on them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use the following path:

```
unanswered/tagged/javascript+php+html5
```

to get unanswered questions with specific tags (using OR between them).

But this still misses the easiness of being just a button, which means it's hard to reload if you want new questions, and you can't ignore tags this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the [release of Custom Filters in question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/295232). The 'Unanswered' tab most closely resembles the 'No accepted answer' option, but 'No answers' might also be worth exploring.

[image]