# Imgur is over capacity - some user avatars fail to load

Tags: bug, profile-picture, imgur

I see a lot of 'white' avatars in the question lists, e.g. [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions) and [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions).
Some user avatars aren't loaded, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7K2b.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkMl8.png – they just timeout for me. Sometimes (but not always) I do get a nice "Imgur is over capacity!" image, which I'm (rather surprisingly) able to upload *to imgur* - but you might not see it.

[image]

Comment: Please see the linked post and comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330387/lots-of-broken-images#comment1077834_330387

Comment: Cross-site dupe (that you're already aware of): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386785/1709587

Comment: Nick [is aware of the issue](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1146059664959737856) and is taking care of it.

Comment: I think it was automatically retracted because of the reverse-close?

Comment: @ShaWiz **I** didn't retract anything, probably someone else did it or cleared it somehow. Clearer or not, I don't exactly like when an older question is closed as a dupe of a new one, especially if the new one is posted closely after the older one. I am pretty sure I didn't retract my vote.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist It was cleared automatically because the other question was closed as a duplicate, making the vote invalid (can no longer close in the other direction).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist this one here is asked in a more clear way and got a useful answer. No reason to close it as dupe just because it was posted a minute after other similar bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell Cloudflare is down now, which is factually a global crisis.

There's not much we can do than to hope that Cloudflare recovers.

**Edit**: Cloudflare seems to be back now.