# (At a minimum) questions custom filter seems to not be updating properly

Tags: support, bug, tags, filtering, custom-filters

Here's the top of my filter:

[image: Top of filter]

One of the questions in that top of the view: [Entity Framework: Exclude audit properties from migration changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888570/entity-framework-exclude-audit-properties-from-migration-changes)

Confirmed as submitted 4 minutes ago.

If I navigate to said question via the link (and normal left click to keep in the same window), then navigate back, the top of my filtered list now presents me with:

[image: After hitting "back" from a question]

Now, the top question from the filter is [SQL how to count the number of relations between two tables and include zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803167/sql-how-to-count-the-number-of-relations-between-two-tables-and-include-zeroes).  Which states it was asked 24 seconds ago, but the question is actually from September 5th.

I'm not sure if there are other cases that this can happen but thought I'd throw it out there.

Here is the full content of the filter:

[image: Filter]

Comment: One thing that needs to clarified: did it take a short time for the browser to reload the new data from the network, or was it instantly shown die to the cache? Most pages on SE (including question list) are cached, so navigating using "back" button will load the cached page instead. Though, the date difference is somewhat surprising, why your browser cached sooo far away.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. kinda hard to say, at a glance it seems to take about the same amount of time whether or not I'm navigating to the filter initially, or via back button.  It's pretty instantaneous either way, then some screen redrawing as data comes in.

Comment: [tag:tag-filters] if for questions about https://stackexchange.com/filters. This question is about a different type of "filter", custom filters. There is already a tag for them [tag:custom-filters]. Rel. [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement)