# Can we have the Interesting, Hot, Weekly, Monthly filter options back when looking at a filter?

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

Can we have the <kbd>Interesting</kbd><kbd>Hot</kbd><kbd>Weekly</kbd><kbd>Monthly</kbd> filter options back, when looking at a filter as per this screenshot:

[image: screenshot from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330527/615969 as it shows the buttons in question]

There does not appear to be a way to emulate this functionality with the new features, and as a casual reader most of the time, I mostly used these filters to find interesting questions and answers to read.

It is really useful to see what the community sees as most useful for a given tag, for new users to that domain.  The new filters give the extremes of the most recent changes (new or modified) or most viewed over all time (currently,

If there is a way of emulating this functionality, that would also be acceptable.

It is possible to view these from the front page (again, see screenshot) but not possible to see the same, but restricted to tags.  So I can't see, for example, the top [python](/questions/tagged/python) questions over the last week.