# How to swap order of Custom Filters?

Tags: feature-request, support, custom-filters

How can I swap the order of Custom Filters?

[image]

Comment: Related to this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330330/312043

Comment: Can you share the source code or link?

Comment: @HendryRaudsepp this is one the right side column of any Stack Exchange site main page, for example [Create a costum filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?edited=true) on SO.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://prnt.sc/vq4y42

Comment: @HendryRaudsepp yes, after you save the custom filter a list like in the screenshot will show right above the link. The red dot appears indicating there are new questions on your custom filter.