# Add an option to weed out questions I've answered in custom filters

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

When making a custom filter with my tags/other criteria, I noticed that it lists a lot of questions that I've already answered.  I apply these filters to look for questions where I can provide a (possibly) helpful answer, and the number of questions I can't answer grows and grows as the number of answers I have posted increases.  Can we please add an option to exclude these questions from our filters?

[image]

Comment: For custom filters you have the option to exclude questions with answers or questions with accepted answers. https://i.imgur.com/nwkHHCN.png

Comment: Not a duplicate, since the duplicate target question reads:"is it possible to?" While this is a request for integrating the feature in a specific part of the site.

Comment: @bad_coder Also, the duplicate asks about that feature in the *search*, not the filters.  I agree it's very similar, but I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Previously [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330356/282094) and [denied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1077745_330356).