# Separate tab for not accepted unanswered and answered questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, unanswered-questions, homepage

In the [unanswered tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) (pictured below) we have various types of questions grouped together.

To quote the FAQ: "[Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/282094)"

> "The Unanswered Questions tab shows questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer. (That includes questions with no answers at all.)".

Can we consider a separate tab for questions which have not received any answers.

[image]

Comment: from my picture,  I think there we should place a new tab option for separate the questions, because in Stack overflow millions of questions, _Personal Opinion_

Comment: Why don't you just search: `answers:0`

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this for yourself using **[Custom Filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement)**

Begin with starting a custom filter:

[image]

Then click: "Save custom filter” and add a name:

[image]

Now there is a custom tab for you with unanswered question and your favourite tags:

[image]