# Why are Filter Subscriptions public? And can that be changed?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, privacy, tag-filters, subscription

A while ago, I discovered the [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) feature on stackexchange.com <sup>(not to be confused with [custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/348196) on individual sites)</sup> and wanted to use it to receive email notifications about certain tags that only get questions every once in a while. However, I quickly discovered that filter subscriptions are displayed publicly (you can visit anyone's [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions) and find out which filters he/she has chosen to receive emails about), which discouraged me from using the feature.

**Is there a good reason for making this information public?**

Here's a list of similar pieces of information that are kept private:

- Watched Tags.
- Custom Filters.
- [Bookmarks were recently replaced with Saves and made private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/348196).

I believe that exposing the fact that someone explicitly wants to receive email notifications about certain tags is somewhat of a privacy issue (which could be more important on some sites than others).

**Would it be possible to make filter subscriptions private?**

Comment: In the past almost anything was public, that's just one relic of that past.

Comment: Alternatively, anyone can subscribe to the filter's RSS Feed privately on the bottom right of the list instead.